# Mouse click sending me message multiple times in c++

Tags: c++, win32gui

This is my code:-

```
DWORD WINAPI ThreadMouse(void* data){
    while (1){
        //Check the mouse left button is pressed or not
        if ((GetKeyState(VK_LBUTTON) & 0x8000) != 0)
        {
            MessageBox(NULL, L"Left Clicked", L"", NULL);
            break;
        }
        //Check the mouse right button is pressed or not
        if ((GetKeyState(VK_RBUTTON) & 0x100) != 0)
        {
            MessageBox(NULL, L"Right Clicked", L"", NULL);
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I am getting the message multiple times instead of once

Comment: Perhaps when you *click* to close the `MessageBox` you trigger a new mouse event?

Comment: When i click left button of my mouse once all the messagebox appears

Comment: I don't know WINAPI, but could it be two events for `mouse press down` and `mouse press up` ?

Comment: Yes i also want to know whether it is happening because of the different mouse events or there is any other way to handle mouse events

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a thread, which polls the state of the mouse.

Not something that gets mouse events.

Windows can receive events.

I have a project with :-

```
class CImageDisplay :
public wxScrolledWindow,
public IToolTarget
{
   /// omitted
     void OnMouseDClick( wxMouseEvent& mouseEvent );
     void OnMouseUp( wxMouseEvent& mouseEvent );

};
```

Where `wxScrolledWindow` is derived from wxWindow.
That declares functions for the mouse events.

In the cpp file, I have...

```
BEGIN_EVENT_TABLE(CImageDisplay, wxScrolledWindow)
    EVT_MOTION(CImageDisplay::OnMouseMove )
    EVT_LEFT_DOWN(CImageDisplay::OnMouseDown )
    EVT_LEFT_DCLICK(CImageDisplay::OnMouseDClick )
    EVT_LEFT_UP(CImageDisplay::OnMouseUp )
   // omitted
END_EVENT_TABLE()
```

This tells wx to call my functions when the events (`EVT_*` occurs).
Then I can track the mouse events as they happen, but otherwise my code is not doing anything.

Check out the wx documentation (e.g. [wx documentation mouse events](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_mouse_event.html) for what events are available, and what limitations they have.

Check out the samples - e.g. plot.cpp which uses mouse events.

Comment: Yes this is a thread. Is there is any other way for catching mouse events

Comment: If your thread does not have a GUI for the user to interact with, you have two choices: 1) use `SetWindowsHookEx()` to hook the mouse, or 2) give your thread a hidden window and then use `RegisterRawInputDevices()` to have the mouse send `WM_INPUT` messages to it.

Answer (score 0):

Your thread does not have a GUI for the user to interact with, so its key state is never updated.  Each thread has its own key state, which is updated during UI message processing.

If you want to monitor the mouse in a thread without a GUI, you have two choices:

1. use [`SetWindowsHookEx()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644990(v=vs.85).aspx) to hook the mouse using a `WH_MOUSE` or `WH_MOUSE_LL` hook.  The thread will need a message loop to service the hook.
2. Have your thread create a hidden window (and message loop) and then use [`RegisterRawInputDevices()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645600(v=vs.85).aspx) to have the mouse send [`WM_INPUT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645590(v=vs.85).aspx) messages to your window.